# Passing second user model data to a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have 2 User models, one is `User` and other is `OrgUser` for company users.
I'm trying to pass `OrgUser` to a `OrgUserController` and display single company user in `show` method. But I always get an empty object.

User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'verified', 'verification_token',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'verification_token',
];
```

OrgUser Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class OrgUser extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'verified', 'verification_token', 'admin'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 'verification_token',
];
```

OrgUserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\OrgUser;

use App\Http\Resources\OrgUserResource;
use App\OrgUser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;

class OrgUserController extends ApiController
{
public function show(OrgUser $orgUser)
{
//        OrgUserResource::withoutWrapping();
//
//        return new OrgUserResource($orgUser);

    return $orgUser;
}
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('orgusers', 'OrgUser\OrgUserController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

Is there something that I would need to add to OrgUser model so I could pass data to controller like that? Because it works if I pass $id.

Comment: show definition of your route which uses this controller method

Comment: Route::resource('orgusers', 'OrgUser\OrgUserController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Comment: what url are you visiting to test it?  `/orgusers/1234`?

Comment: Can you add the route to your question @Guitarguy753?

Comment: yes it is /orgusers/{id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It seems the problem was with naming in show method. I need to pass $orguser and not $orgUser. Because in my route it was /orgusers/{orguser}.

Answer (score -1):

The `show` function should be accepting the `$id` rather than the model. If you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $orgUser = OrgUser::find($id);

    return $orgUser;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working like that. But I was wondering why it is not working when with `OrgUser $orgUser`. Because in all other controllers I can pass data like that.

Comment: Maybe you would have an idea where to look?